# Xamarin Forms Can not parse a DateTime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get this date 4th April 2021 12:00 which is todays date into a DateTime object.
I am in the UK and the emulator's locale is set to GB summer time and the format looks correct in it's setting page.
I have a date as a string:

`string dateTimeStr = "08-04-2021 12:00";`
I have tried this:

`t = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeStr);`
I get a datetime object of

`4th Aug 2021 12:00`
How can I parse a date as a string to DateTime and be sure that the month and the day will not be swapped?

Comment: Use `ParseExact` and specify the format explicitly. Note that if you have any control over the format, I'd strongly recommend using an ISO date format instead, to avoid ambiguity - that would be 2021-04-08 for April 8th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeStr, "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

you can use `ParseExact` and mention the date format as per your requirement.

Comment: That's not the date format of the string involved though... if the OP uses that string, it will still fail. (Even as a sample format it's not great, given that it uses `hh` instead of `HH` and has no am/pm indicator.)